# Loss of data validation lists after deleting shape on the same sheet

Tags: excel-2010, shapes, validation

I'm having sheet with data validation lists on it. I'm also inserting some shapes on it but after deleting any shape all my data validation lists are gone.

Here is how I'm deleting shapes:

```
If Target.Value = "" Then
    For Each sh In Sheets(3).Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row)) Is Nothing Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Looking at this problem of mine data validation list is also considered as shape. So, could I somehow isolate shapes only in column A and delete them.

Any idea why this is happening and how can it be solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
If Target.Value = "" Then
     For Each sh In Sheets(3).Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row)) Is Nothing Then
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                sh.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

I'm deleting pictures so ... :-)